# The time before and after 1900

Tags: phrase-requests

What should I write if I mean the time before and after 1900 (summa summarum about 30 years).
I am not a native speaker that's why I am not able to decide which expression is right.
My ideas are:
- at/around the turn of the 19th to the 20th century
- at/around the turn of the 19th - 20th century
- at/around the turn of the 20th century
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "Around 1900"? Does this refer to a specific country or subject, because there may be names for the period in certain areas, like "Belle Époque" (used especially of France, but c. 1871-1914), or references to monarchy, government, artistic movement, etc?

Comment: "Belle Époque" is a very good example. How could one describe this period the way I need?